# Vue Testing Library - Error in beforeCreate hook: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'init')"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, testing-library, jest-dom

I am writing my very first tests using `@testing-library/vue`. I am using Vue 2.7 and the version for `testing-library/vue` is `^5.6.1`. Here is the component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p data-testid="custom-element">Hello world</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({

  }),
  async mounted() {
    console.log('test component mounted');
  }
};
</script>
```

and here is the test so far:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render } from '@testing-library/vue';
import TestComponent from '../../src/views/Plan/PlanResults/TestComponent.vue';
import { store } from '../../src/store';

it('renders test correctly', async () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(TestComponent);
  console.log('rendered');
  expect(getByTestId('custom-element')).toHaveTextContent('Hello World');
});
```

I am importing the Vuex store because the component and the test eventually need to rely on it. The issue is, simply including this import makes the test fail immediately with the following:

```
 FAIL  tests/integration/singleDataset.spec.js
  ✕ renders test correctly (10ms)

  ● renders test correctly

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'init')

       5 |
       6 | it('renders test correctly', async () => {
    >  7 |   const { getByTestId } = render(TestComponent);
         |                           ^
       8 |   console.log('rendered');
       9 |   expect(getByTestId('custom-element')).toHaveTextContent('Hello world');
      10 | });
```

Reading further through the logs, I get to this underlying error:

```
console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:569
    [Vue warn]: Error in beforeCreate hook: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'init')"
    
    (found in <Root>)
```

Commenting out the `import { store } from '../../src/store'` line with *no* other changes makes the test run fine. Including the import but commenting out `const { getByTestId } = render(TestComponent);` also throws no errors. Only with the store imported and `render()` being called does this fail as described. The store itself also works perfectly when running the actual app, so I really have no idea why it's making the test fail despite `store` not even being passed to `render()` right now. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: is there any variable in store called 'init'?

Comment: @LiteralMetaphore I keep running into this too recently. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @AlexBass I had several problems with this before I got it to work. I ended up with something like this:
`import store from '../../../src/store';`
So, importing store as the default export instead of named.
`const componentOptions = {store, router, props: planResultsProps};`
Making an object for component options which includes the store and router in my case, and the props for the component you're testing, and finally calling:
`const instance = render(PlanResults, componentOptions);`
Essentially the test needs to create its own instance of the store. Hope this helps

Comment: @LiteralMetaphore thanks for the follow up! I am not using a store in my project, but importing my components separately rather than from our `~/lib/components/index.ts` resolved it. There were probably too many things being imported and it somehow fixed the issue. The cause remains a mystery 